# If an Arcane Archer fighter misses with an Arcane Shot, does that expend a use of the feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, fighter, arcane-archer

For example; if a third level Arcane Archer fighter chose to fire a 'Bursting Shot' and missed the target, is one of his uses of the Arcane Shot class feature expended?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

(Xanathar's Guide to Everything, page 28)

Under **Arcane shot**, when first describing the feature it says:

> Once per turn when you fire an arrow from a shortbow or longbow as part of the Attack action, you can apply one of your Arcane Shot options to that arrow. **You decide to use the option when the arrow hits a creature, unless the option doesn’t involve an attack roll**. You have two uses of this ability, and you regain all expended uses of it when you finish a short or long rest.

And, it says:

> **Bursting Arrow**
>
> You imbue your arrow with force energy drawn from the school of evocation. The energy detonates after your attack. **Immediately after the arrow hits the creature,** the target and all other creatures within 10 feet of it take 2d6 force damage each.

(Emphasis mine)

So I don't think you use the feature until you know that attack was successful, so you wouldn't lose the feature on a miss.

Comment: On the otherhand, you apparently can't use it on something that isn't a creature, such as animated armor, which is a construct.

Comment: @Vaelus Animated Armor is a creature, and has the construct creature type. Constructs differ from most other creature types (for example Cure Wounds has no effect on them), but they are still creatures. [Monster Manual p.6]